# How do I have session available in PHP application which makes HTTP requests to java servlets using cURL (Session is started in servlet)?

Tags: php, session, curl

I have a web service made using Java Servlet and I can access that using curl in PHP which returns data in JSON. Now the problem is I start session in java servlet and I want to have that session in PHP after the request is made. How can I do it?

Comment: you want php to have direct access to the session data the servlet is storing? or just have php act as a browser USING that session via the servlet, as if it was a real person sitting at a browser?

Comment: I have an application in PHP (used by a user) which makes request to Web Service (Java Servlet) and returns JSON. But when I first invoke the web service, it starts the session and I want to store it until the session of person using PHP application expires.

Comment: I just want the session started in java servlet on first request to be available in client php application.